# How to color vertices of a cube?

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, vertex-colors

I do some tests of 3D projection, I am using some references mesh like a cube. However, I need to colorize the vertices of a cube. Is it possible to do that?

[image: cube]

Comment: Do you mean "Vertex paint" or something else?

Comment: @parameciostudio, I need to colorize the 4 top vertex by 4 differents colors  in order to get 4 different colored points where I render. I tried with vertex paint but when I render i have not the colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *Vertex Paint*

1. Select the cube and toggle Vertex Paint

[image]

2. Set a color from the Tools Panel on the left, then click a vertex to apply. Repeat for every vertex
   [image]

### INTERNAL RENDER

Check *Vertex Color Paint* in the Material Panel to render Vertex Colors
 [image]

### CYCLES RENDER

In *Node Editor*: Add > Input > Vertex Colors > select Vertex Color Layer...
[image]

Comment: I am doing that in cycle render.  I can not reach the 3 step. How Can reach it?

Comment: @startingBlender I've edited my anwser