# How to color line set with vertex colors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, vertex-colors

I would like to use vertex colors to paint an extruded line set but do not succeed to do it.

In detail, I export a scene in X3D format from paraview. It consist of a panels and lines that are colored according to a VTK field (cf. picture below).
[image: Paraview scene]

Then when I import this X3D file into Blender, I get these three fields :--

- Shape_IndexdedFaceSet     (for ship panels)
- Shape_IndexdedFaceSet.001 (for free surface)
- Shape_IndexdedLineSet     (for ship lines : tower)

I have no problem to show vertex colors on the FaceSet (using an attribute and material output in cycles rendering mode) but the same does'nt work for the Bevel extruded LineSet (cf. picture below where the lines remain desperately black).
[image: Cycles for LineSet material output]
[image: Blender rendering]

Any idea how to do that ? Is there a hidden option I missed ?

Comment: Is the mast imported as a a mesh or a curve.  Related [1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/909/how-can-i-set-and-get-the-vertex-color-property) [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38912/how-to-color-vertices-of-a-cube)

Comment: I think it's a curve. Where can I check that ?

Comment: Select it. Will have a curve for data icon on properties panel. Or go into edit mode (will be a curve menu) or in python console type `C.object.type` or the tools panel will have tools for curves.

Comment: I confirm it is a curve

Comment: Could convert to mesh `object > convert to > mesh` and use method outlined in link above. As for colouring curve in cycles, that's outside my field.

Comment: After you've converted it to mesh you can simply paint it like the other mesh objects.

Comment: Can you [upload a `.blend` file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: unfortunately I can't provide the .blend file for this project but I will try to reproduce the situation on another geometry I can share whenver I have time